# Illegal double '[redacted]' value found during parsing

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, I'm creating a log in system. When I am dealing with the data stored in a MySQL database, I get the following error:

> > Illegal double '200970e19291' value found during parsing

with the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();    // Session start

$username = $_POST['username']; // Gets the username from the login page
$password = $_POST['password']; // Gets the password.
$salt = "oijahsfdapsf80efdjnsdjp"; // Salt

// Add the salt
$salt .= $password; // The password is now: oijahsfdapsf80efdjnsdjp_PLUS_THE_USERS_PASSWORD
$password = $salt; // Change the password var to contain the salt

// Encryption
$password = md5($password); // woo

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Serrano Login</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

// Connect to your database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('serrano');

$query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE password = ".$password." LIMIT 1"; 

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username); // just to be sure.

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $resusername = $row['username']; // username from DB
    $respassword = $row['password']; // password from DB
    $resemail = $row['email']; // email from db

}

// Are they a valid user?
if ($respassword == $password) {
    // Yes they are.
    // Lets put some data in our session vars and mark them as logged in.
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "1";
    $_SESSION['email'] = $resemail;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $resusername;
    echo "Congrats, Your logged in"; // YAY
}else{
    // No, Lets mark them as invalid.
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "0";
    echo "Sorry, Invalid details"; // Nay
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: The password isn't delimited. Stop using mysql_* functions and move to PDO.

Comment: Also, don't use md5 to hash passwords, and add a salt.

Comment: What is a delimited password?

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Wait a minute. Doesn't this script accept *any* user name? Won't it just fetch the first record - any record - with the password supplied, and log the client in as that user? You are checking for the password twice, but never for the user name.

Comment: @EmilVikström Nice nitpicking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't quoted the password 'value' you're inserting, so to MySQL it's appearing as a mangled number.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE password = '".$password."' LIMIT 1"; 
                                                  ^---missing   ^---missing
```

or better yet:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE password = '$password' LIMIT 1";
```